# Use Visio with Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, visio

Is it feasible to use a SharePoint list (via Access) and create an Organisation document in Visio. Any pointers in the correct direction, if this is possible would be appreciated.  Ideally I want to press a button in Access to achieve this. Determined to persevere, but not to waste time and effort

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create data-connected, dynamic diagrams in Visio. And yes, a SharePoint list can be used as source as well:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-an-external-list-with-Visio-4c8d76e7-2379-41f3-a100-0aa6acb2e1da

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Roadmap-Display-a-data-connected-Visio-drawing-in-a-SharePoint-web-part-405f52fa-7866-4d2d-b83b-6b84cfba987a

You don't even need Access in the process...

Comment: What a very poor answer